# Как случше объеденять файлы

Tags: qt, файлы

Пишу не большой довнлоадер на QT, делит файлы на части и скачивает выкидывая на диск filename_part_1, filename_part_2 и тп.

Какой самый быстрый и наиболее адкеватный по ресурсоемкасти способ для их объеденения стоит использовать?

Answer (score 1):

Набросал простой метод объединения частей файлов в один результирующий файл:

```
bool mergeParts(const QString& resultFileName, const QStringList& partsFileNames)
{
  qint64 totalSize = 0;
  QStringListIterator it(partsFileNames);
  while (it.hasNext()) {
    totalSize += QFile(it.next()).size();
  }

  QFile result(resultFileName);
  result.resize(totalSize);
  if (result.open(QFile::WriteOnly)) {
    it.toFront();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
      QFile part(it.next());
      if (part.open(QFile::ReadOnly)) {
        result.write(part.readAll());
        result.flush();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

За вами остаётся:

- следить, чтобы части файлов были переданы в правильном порядке;
- проверять, хватает ли места на диске, куда пишете результат;
- обрабатывать ошибки при открытии файлов;
- убеждаться в том, чтобы количество считанных байт из файла-части было равно количеству записанных байт в файл-результат;
- ...
- PROFIT

Проверьте насколько вас устраивает скорость обработки. Может быть стоит сэкономить на вызовах конструкторов `QFile`?

Comment: У меня не возникает проблем с написание метода для объеденения файлов, я ищу наиболее производительный на этом этапе вы единоверменно выгружаете все в память http://take.ms/52M68 что, как я предполгоаю не есть хорошо...

Comment: "Всё" - это полное содержимое каждого кусочка в отдельности. Если вы планируете, что эти кусочки будут очень большими, то кто ж вам запрещает читать в буфер фиксированного размера? Можете вообще хоть по-байтово читать/записывать.

Comment: Кусочки по 500мб каждый. в том то и вопрос, как будет правильнее, а не в том как я могу их читать